# Parent process won't write correctly to lua child process stdin

Tags: process, lua, dart, stdin, child-process

I have a dart program, called file.dart, like so:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  final file = Directory.current.path + '/file.lua';

  Process.start('lua', [file]).then((Process process) {
    print('opened process');
    process.stdout.pipe(stdout);
    process.stdin.add([4]);
    process.stdin.flush().then((blah) => print('flushed'));
  });
}
```

I have a lua program, called file.lua, like so:

```
print('starting to read')
local data = io.stdin:read()
print('i read it ', data)
```

when i run the dart program this is what happens:

```
$ dart file.dart 
opened process
flushed
starting to read
```

then it just sits there forever. the lua read is blocking and it never picks up the bytes written by the dart process.

I put a delay on the dart process so that it wrote and flushed a second later. the output of running that was

```
$ dart file.dart 
opened process
starting to read
flushed
```

but it still hung up forever.

So i have 2 questions:

1) Why won't the lua process pick up the byte that the dart process wrote?

2) Is there a super easy way to make the lua read non-blocking? So that lua would poll instead of block.

Please put the number of the question that you are answering as you answer it. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried sending a `\n` after `[4]`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by sending a '\n\ or a new-line byte at then end of my transmissions!

Comment: Can you edit your answer and provide the working code please ?